# Bootstrap 3: Set custom width with input-group/input-group-addon and horizontal labels

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to control the size of my input elements using the class `.col-lg-*` outlined [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-sizes) on the bootstrap website.  However, putting the `<span>` element inside of a div completely messes it up:

**HTML with div:**

```
<div class="input-group input-group-lg">
  <label for="" class="control-label">Paycheck</label>
  <div class="col-lg-10">
    <span class="input-group-addon">$</span> 
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="">
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: HTML with div]

**How can I set the width of the input elements so that they are all the same?**

I want the left margin of each input element to be flush like so:

[image: lined-up input elements]

This is what it looks like now:

[image: current state]

This is my current HTML:

```
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="content">
            <h2>Income</h2>
        <form class="form-income form-horizontal" role="form">

            <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
            <label for="" class="control-label">Paycheck</label>
                <span class="input-group-addon">$</span> 
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="">
            </div>

            <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
            <label for="" class="control-label">Investments</label>
                <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id=""> 
            </div>

            <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
            <label for="" class="control-label">Other</label>
                <span class="input-group-addon">$</span> 
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="">
            </div>

            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Update</button>
        </form>

        </div>
```

### LIVE EXAMPLE: http://jsfiddle.net/jfXUr/

Comment: Only `.form-control` and `.input-group-addon` elements should go inside `.input-group` containers. Use `.form-group` to group your labels and `.input-group` elements

Comment: How's this - http://jsfiddle.net/jfXUr/1/ ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As per my comment above, try grouping the label and `.input-group` together with a `.form-group` container.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="" class="control-label">Paycheck</label>
    <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
        <span class="input-group-addon">$</span> 
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/jfXUr/1/

Comment: Thanks Phil.  What you did looks fine, but I'd really like the labels to show beside the input elements.  Is that possible?

Comment: @Keven For that, you should be using [`.form-horizontal`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal). You'll need to add the `col-` classes to your labels and `.input-group` elements for sizing

Comment: I'm already using `.form-horizontal` in my form element.  So it should work if I put the `.input-group` class on my labels?  Any way you could do a fiddle to show me what you mean?

Comment: @Keven Ah, your fiddle didn't have form-horizontal. Here's a horizontal example - http://jsfiddle.net/jfXUr/3/. Note the `col-` classes on the labels and input groups. I've used `xs` columns so it work in JSFiddle's tiny windows

Comment: Thanks Phil!!  You're awesome.  It worked.  I did notice the `xs`.  I will change that to fit my needs.  Have a good one!