# Match the width of input-group with input in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have created a popup using bootstrap modal. Here is how it looks like

[image: Current modal]

I want to make the `input` and `input-group` elements to be of same width and start at the same position like mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20277449/bootstrap-3-set-custom-width-with-input-group-input-group-addon-and-horizontal) question. I have tried using `form-group` as mentioned in its [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20278063/2246380) but it doesn't work. I am new to bootstrap and JavaScript.

**HTML code**

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="modal fade" id="apstMoleculeModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Enter Information</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">                          
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-xs-3">Name</label>
                        <div class="controls col-xs-9">
                            <input type="text"  placeholder="Enter Name">
                            &nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" title="Help info"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-xs-3">Place</label>
                        <div class="controls col-xs-9">
                            <input type="text"  placeholder="Enter Place">
                            &nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" title="Help info"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-xs-3">Cost</label>
                        <div class="controls col-xs-9 input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                            <input type="text"  placeholder="0.00">
                            &nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" title="Help info" ></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>                      
                </div> <!-- modal-body -->

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: try opening it in chrome > go to dev options and down the right hand side will tell you the css acting on the 'selected' part of the html. something similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27276353/3436942)

Comment: it doesn't open in chrome as chrome prevents cross scripts

Comment: firefox also has dev tools available - ever heard of firebug (i think its called)? -

Comment: can you share the url so we can see?

Comment: @jbutler483 I am looking at it there is not specified width for the  input to act that way.

Comment: @ShowcaseImagery Its in my local system in development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## DEMO: https://jsbin.com/xewevu/1/

[image]

*Form in wrong location, not using the correct classes on the input and you need to write custom css or use even more wrappers and the grid system, which is really overkill IMO.*

The beauty of this approach is that if you decided to use `.col-sm` instead of `xs`, then the `.help` won't stack.

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="apstMoleculeModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Enter Information</h4>
         </div>
         <form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="modal-body">
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-xs-3">Name</label>
                  <div class="controls col-xs-9">
                     <span class="help glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" title="Help info"></span>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name">
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-xs-3">Place</label>
                  <div class="controls col-xs-9">
                     <span class="help glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" title="Help info"></span>
                     <input type="text"  class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Place">
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-xs-3">Cost</label>
                  <div class="controls col-xs-9">
                     <span class="help glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" title="Help info"></span>
                     <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0.00">
                        </span>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <!-- modal-body -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
         </form>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#apstMoleculeModal .form-group {
 padding-right:20px;
  position:relative;
}

#apstMoleculeModal .help {
 position:absolute;
 right:-8px;
 top:12px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and explanation I prefer a solution not involving css

Comment: That's your preference, however GetBootstrap.com, most of the examples, all of the showcase sites, every single theme for sale, all use custom CSS, GetBootstrap.com uses a lot.

Comment: I did go through getbootstrap.com and implemented this solution and added custom css files. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You're not quite using the classes for `col-*-*` right, and your inputs are also missing classes. Take a look at this Bootply:

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/AFCNZOmR1V)

Here to see what I mean.

Here's the code (Removed all Modals so I could directly edit it)

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-3">Name</label>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <input class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Enter Name" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" title="Help info"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-3">Place</label>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <input class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Enter Place" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" title="Help info"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-3">Cost</label>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
        <input class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="0.00" type="text">
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" title="Help info"></span>
    </div>
  </div>                      
</form>
```

**Please Note:**

You may have to change the size of the `col-xs-*` to fit in the modal correctly.